# How do I install zlib on Debian 6?

Tags: installation, debian, packages

I want to install zlib on Debian 6. For this, I think I would use `apt-get install`, but I don't know which package to use.  The package zlib doesn't exist, and if I install zlibc (which sounds most appropriate), running `zlib -version` brings up the error `command not found`.  (I used `apt-file search zlib` to find zlibc.)

Is there another package which contains zlib, and how do I find this package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `zlib` command does not exist:

```
$ dpkg -L zlib1g
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/zlib1g
/usr/share/doc/zlib1g/copyright
/usr/share/doc/zlib1g/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/zlib1g/changelog.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
/usr/lib/libz.so.1
```

It is a library.

If you are searching for anything use `apt-cache search`.

And if you need a command to compress use either `gzip` or `zip`.

Answer (score 34):

```
sudo apt install zlib1g
```

Possibly

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev
```

as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I use apt-get install zlibg1, I get "zlibg1 is allready the newest version"... After installing zlib1g-dev, "which zlib" is still empty.

Comment: I'm noticing a `/usr/lib/libz.so`.  Maybe Debian changed the name of it.

Comment: If you're using the zip extension on the docker php image, you'll need zlib1g-dev